# HTML Tidy - Add opening tags, instead of removing closing tags?

Tags: c#, htmltidy

Is it possible to configure HTML Tidy in the following way:

Given the html:

```
lorem ipsum</em> dolar sit amet.</p>
```

To have it generate

```
<p><em>lorem ipsum</em> dolar sit amet.</p>
```

Instead of just stripping out the closing tags?

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Why not `<p>lorem <em>ipsum</em> dolar sit amet.</p>`? :)  It can't guess where to put the tag...but it can remove without needing to, that's why the remove is supported, but this isn't.

Comment: I was hoping that it might be an option somewhere as I would say it's not totally unreasonable to want it to just generate them on the front?

Comment: On the front of what? As Nick said, a safe option might be to add it in front of the word preceding the `</em>`, but this ending tag can even not be after a word. It can mark a sentence, a line, a paragraph, etc. Hard to automate in a consistent and satisfying way.
A better choice would be to mark these instances and have a tool to iterate among them interactively so the user can add manually where it makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically agree with Sky Sanders answer. except for:

> You would be expecting the simple tidy parser to infer prior intent.

You could write a parser that provides the described functionality just without having to infer any intent, working just deterministic. One could easily (yeah, more or less easily :) ) write an algorithm that does the job. The idea would be:

### Adding closing tags

After all, this can be done with HTML Tidy already, and every browser/parser does it implicitly already (Im not speaking about valid XHTML here):

```
<div>some <span><em>text</span> here</div>
```

gets

```
<div>some <span><em>text</em></span> here</div>
```

### Adding opening tags

We could now go and make some algorithm that analyses the following, beginning at the end of the string and searching reversely:

```
<div>some <span>text</em></span> here</div>
```

to produce the following one, because it sees that the `em` tag is embedded in the `span` tag.

```
<div>some <span><em>text</em></span> here</div>
```

### Combining these two

Now we have to write an algorithm that does both adding missing closing and opening tags. Now lets take this html fragment:

```
<div>some <span>text</em> here</div>
```

First apply the 'add all missing closing tags' method:

```
<div>some <span>text</em> here</span></div>
```

The algorithm is assuming here that every closing and opening tag that comes after `<span>` is embedded in the `span`. It only stops if it sees a closing tag for some opening tag that was before the `<span>`. In this case this is `</div>`, that had a valid opening tag `<div>` before. Then apply the same semantics in a reverse search, like described before:

```
<div>some <span><em>text</em> here</span></div>
```

et voila.

### Does that all make sense?

In my opinion: No. It is technically possible, but not worth the effort. You would have to implement your own parser, together with this pseudo-intelligent methods described above. Additionally this would apply a semantic to html that isnt there anyway: Every browser/parser just ignores isolated closing tags, so why would you want to pay attention to them?

If I couldnt convince you yet, consider the semantics of html:

`some <b>text</b> here` reads like: "print 'some'. start rendering bold. print 'text'. stop rendering bold. print 'here'."

While:

`some text</b> here` reads like: "print 'some text'. stop rendering bold." "What? I didnt even start rendering anything bold!? I'll just ignore that..." :)

Answer (score 2):

No. HTML Tidy does not provide that option.

You would be expecting the simple tidy parser to infer prior intent.

Determining when a tag must be closed, whether it was intended to be closed at that point or not, can be accomplished by the parser using the rules of html.

Comment: +1. What I wanted to say in a comment, didnt fit into these 600 chars :), so I wrote another answer.